# I need the sum of each year separately for a specific product and a specific year

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT  TRX_DATE, SUM( UNIT_SELLING_PRICE) 
FROM ra_customer_trx_lines_all , ra_customer_trx_all
WHERE 
DESCRIPTION LIKE '%مبيعات نيتروجين سائل%'
GROUP BY  DESCRIPTION ,TRX_DATE
```

[the failed result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5WYG.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a *year*, then extract it from the date column:

```
  SELECT EXTRACT (YEAR FROM trx_date) year, 
         SUM (unit_selling_price) total
    FROM ra_customer_trx_lines_all, ra_customer_trx_all
   WHERE description LIKE '%مبيعات نيتروجين سائل%'
GROUP BY description, EXTRACT (YEAR FROM trx_date)
```

You additionally put `description` into the `group by` clause, but it's not part of the `select` column list. It doesn't have to be, but - I'say that you'd actually *want* it to be:

```
  SELECT EXTRACT (YEAR FROM trx_date) year, 
         description,                           --> this
         SUM (unit_selling_price) total
```

Note that you're creating a Cartesian product (two tables which aren't joined by anything), so you'll *cross join* all rows from `ra_customer_trx_lines_all` with all rows from `ra_customer_trx_all` (and then filter by `description`).

Finally, you should always use table aliases when referencing columns. The way you wrote it, it is unknown which column belongs to which table. You might even get an error if the same column exists in both tables (it'll become *ambiguous*).

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
SELECT  EXTRACT (YEAR FROM trx_date), SUM( UNIT_SELLING_PRICE) 
FROM ra_customer_trx_lines_all , ra_customer_trx_all
WHERE 
DESCRIPTION LIKE '%مبيعات نيتروجين سائل%'
GROUP BY  DESCRIPTION ,EXTRACT (YEAR FROM trx_date)
```

Comment: There's no YEAR function in Oracle.

Comment: in oracle `EXTRACT (YEAR FROM date)` use this.

Answer (score 0):

are you missing join statement?

```sql
SELECT  EXTRACT (YEAR FROM trx_date), SUM(UNIT_SELLING_PRICE) 
FROM ra_customer_trx_lines_all a 
join ra_customer_trx_all b on a.some_id = b.some_id
WHERE DESCRIPTION LIKE '%مبيعات نيتروجين سائل%'
GROUP BY EXTRACT (YEAR FROM trx_date)
```

as mentioned previously you may also use specific alias for each column:

```sql
SELECT  EXTRACT (YEAR FROM a.trx_date), SUM(b.UNIT_SELLING_PRICE) 
FROM ra_customer_trx_lines_all a 
join ra_customer_trx_all b on a.trx_id = b.trx_id
WHERE a.DESCRIPTION LIKE '%مبيعات نيتروجين سائل%'
GROUP BY EXTRACT (YEAR FROM a.trx_date)
```